# Lower suspension self locking nut stuck

Tags: suspension, replace, shock-absorber

I'm trying to change the shocks on my 1993 Acura Integra, but I just can't seem to loosen the self-locking nut from the bolt that connects the lower part of the shock to the knuckle. I tried Liquid Wrench and that doesn't seem to do a think, I also tried an impact screwdriver (the kind you hit with a hammer) but nothing seems to make a difference. I'm thinking that the impact didn't work because the way my suspension is mounted allows the whole nut/bolt/shock assembly to twist together a few degrees, but I'm not sure that's a factor. Is there a trick to removing these nuts or should I just go and buy/borrow a beefy impact wrench?

Comment: I haven't had my Integra for quite a few years now so I'm trying to remember the layout of the suspension.  Do you have a picture available?  With that, I might be able to give you a more useful answer.  You are right about the motion in the suspension - if you can borrow / beg / buy one, an electric impact driver is quite likely suitable for loosening things up (for a reasonable price).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the nut off. Out of sheer frustration combined with late night stupidity I put the longest cheater bar on it and jacked up the end of the bar using a hydraulic jack. Surprisingly, it worked even though I was turning it in the wrong direction (that's the reason I hadn't tried that sooner). The nut un-seized and I was able to remove it relatively easily afterward. I guess brute force was the way after all.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having issues like these about 5 years ago, and we ended up having to grip the screw/stud that was sticking out while turning the nut. Does the bolt have a flat piece that you can maybe get a wrench on? Try this if possible. Another option, assuming you are replacing them, vice grip the polished rod with some beefy vice grips and removed the nut. This will damage the polished rod, so only do this if changing the whole assembly.

Comment: I think you are talking about a different nut (the one at the top of the assembly?). I haven't gotten to that part yet, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Are they the pressed in bolts at the bottom? They should have two flat sides where you can place a wrench, or grip them there hopefully. Honestly, if they are still stuck, buy new nuts and bolts and grind them off. Only do this if they are the pressed in kind though.

Comment: Ok, now I am following you. Will gripping the screw not damage the threads? I am worried about breaking the screw loose, but not being able to thread it out.

Comment: I think those are pressed in there... You might want to double check with a parts store or dealer though.